# Pop-up alert based on expiry date when the workbook opens

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, worksheet

I want a message alert pop-up when a reagent is expiring in 7 days and when the reagent is expired, when the workbook opens.

The message should include the reagent that is expired. I attempted this for the 'FA Reagents' (A4:A20) and those reagents expiration dates (C4:C20). Eventually I would like the code to work for all the reagents in this sheet.

Excel Sheet
[image]

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rReagents As Range
    Set rReagents = Range("A4:A20")
    Dim rExpiration As Range
    Set rExpiration = Range("C4:C20")
    Dim lLastrow As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("Reagent-Equipment")
    lLastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With ws
        For i = 2 To lLastrow
            If .Cells(i, 2) = Date + 7 Then MsgBox ("Reagent expiring in 7 days for " & .Cells(i, 1))
            If .Cells(i, 2) = Date Then MsgBox ("Reagent expiring today for " & .Cells(i, 1))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: According to the image, the exp. date is in column C, but you are checking `.Cells(i, 2)`, that's column B

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger. Stepping thru the code (F8) or set breakpoints. Then check the values with the debugger, this usually reveals such problems really fast

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following code of interest

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim myShortDate As String
    Dim myExpired As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Reagent-Equipment")
    
    
    Dim myReagents As Variant
    myReagents = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A4:A20").Value)
    
    Dim myExpiry As Variant
    myExpiry = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("C4:C20").Value)
   
  
    Dim myIndex As Long
    myIndex = 1
    Dim myItem As Variant
    For Each myItem In myReagents
    
        If Now > VBA.CDate(myExpiry(myIndex)) Then
        
            If VBA.Len(myExpired) = 0 Then
                
                myExpired = vbTab & myReagents(myIndex)
            
            Else
            
                myExpired = myExpired & vbCrLf & vbTab & myReagents(myIndex)
                
            End If
        
        ElseIf Now + 7 > VBA.CDate(myExpiry(myIndex)) Then
        
            If VBA.Len(myShortDate) = 0 Then
                
                myShortDate = vbTab & myReagents(myIndex) & " on " & myExpiry(myIndex)
            
            Else
            
                myShortDate = myShortDate & vbCrLf & vbTab & myReagents(myIndex) & " on " & myExpiry(myIndex)
                
            End If
            
        End If
    
        myIndex = myIndex + 1
        
    Next
    
    If VBA.Len(myExpired) > 0 Then
    
        myExpired = "Expired Reagents" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & myExpired & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        
    End If
    
    
    If VBA.Len(myShortDate) > 0 Then
    
        myShortDate = "Reagents due to expire " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & myShortDate & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        
    End If
    
    Dim myMessage As String
    myMessage = myExpired & myShortDate
    
    If VBA.Len(myMessage) > 0 Then
    
        MsgBox myMessage, vbCritical
        
    End If
    

End Sub
```